# Unity: Instantiating prefab appears at wrong location

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

I'm creating a simple text-based puzzle that will have a varied number of clues, determined at runtime. I figured I should do this by instantiating a number of prefabs. Here's what it looks like right now.

[image: image 1]

Notice the transform values. The prefab in Assets has the exact same values.

To test to see if I could instantiate a bunch of Puzzle objects at runtime, I created this simple loop:

```
     for (int x = 1; x < 6; x++)
     {
         Debug.Log(15-x);
         Instantiate(puzzle, new Vector2(0, 15 - x), Quaternion.identity, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform);
     }
```

The idea being all the clones would stack beneath the first Puzzle object. However, this is what happens when I run it:

[image: image 2]

The clones are being stacked at the wrong position. I used the debug log to confirm the correct values are being used for the vector, and I've tried using Vector3 as well. There are a lot of similar questions on the unity forums, but none of those solutions worked for me. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You definitely should use a parent element with a vertical layout group, and spawn your new elements as child of it. It will do exactly what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set positions of canvas elements you need to use the [anchoredPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) of the [RectTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html).

So you need to get your target element's anchoredPosition so you can position the next elements with respect to that.

```cs
    public RectTransform firstPuzzle;
    public GameObject puzzle;

    private void InstantiatePuzzle()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 6; x++)
        {
            RectTransform spawnedPuzzle = Instantiate(puzzle, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform).GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            spawnedPuzzle.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(firstPuzzle.anchoredPosition.x, firstPuzzle.anchoredPosition.y - (50 * x));// 50 is the gap you want it to be.
        }
    }
```

Assign the reference of the first element(Puzzle) which is currently in the inspector and it will start positioning the next elements below that with a gap of 50.

Here is the output.
[image: output]

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I also had to replace the Puzzle objects "Transform" with "RectTransform"